# Why is the .css File Not Changing the Font Family?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a .html file that accesses a style.css file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This is it.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the style.css file:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                /var/www/html/style.css                           
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 100px;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

I know .html file is correctly linking to the .css file because the text is aligned in the middle and the font-size is 80px, but the font-family is not Arial, it is the default Linux Mint font.
If I use < style >  tags inside of the .html file, and change the font-family, it changes, but for some reason it doesn't change when using the .css file.

Comment: Is that the whole code which do you has in your files?

Comment: no, the code within the < p > tags is different, and there are some headings, but that shouldn't matter

Comment: And any other CSS? Could you try adding !important after font-size (like _font-size: 80px !important;_)?

Comment: something may be overwriting that property. It's easy to spot if you inspect it in the browser. Have you tried inspecting the p tag?

Comment: Your p tag? I cannot do this. I doesnt have acces to your files, only you can do it :)

Comment: But if you have it uploaded to web, you can share URL with me

Comment: I tried the !important and it didn't work. I have updated the post with the everything in the style.css file. Just ignore the top text (GNU nano) thats just in the terminal.

Comment: I also tried inspecting the page, nothing appeared to be interfering with the fonts.

Comment: Arial is not a Web font. It has to be installed on the client to be used. That's why we usually  also define fallbacks like `font-family: Arial, sans-serif`. Could it be your problem ?

Comment: @julien.giband But he said _If I use < style > tags inside of the .html file, and change the font-family, it changes_

Comment: WOAH, I just opened the actual web address, and everything had the Arial font, but when I open it with the local ip (127.0.0.1) it doesn't have Arial font. (wwhhaatt?)

Comment: I also just tried using the fall back font family, it still uses the linux mint default.

Comment: Good it is solved, it was a weird problem... :)

Comment: I tried running your code on a local server it works fine. As you mentioned I tried it with external CSS and it works just fine, I don't quite know what you did wrong

Comment: Yes, I also tried to run it locally, and it works for me too. (With external CSS)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very weird problem. If I use the local ip (127.0.0.1), it doesn't use Arial on any of the pages, but on the actual website, everything is in Arial. Since it works technically, I won't complain, but if you know why this is, please comment :)